# Why is 'Alyce' spelled with a Y?

Tags: alyce-kills

In the movie [*Alyce Kills* (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1680051/) there are many deliberate references to [Alice's Adventures in Wonderland by Lewis Carroll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice%27s_Adventures_in_Wonderland).

A few off the top of my head:

- She has a white rabbit statue when she is getting high
- Her visits to the drug dealer are obviously a reference to the tea party with the Mad Hatter
- One of the drug dealers is always asleep and is named "Mouse"
- The song "Go Ask Alice" is heard playing
- She is heard saying "Off with her head" which is a quote from the Queen of Hearts
- And last but not least, her friend's name is Carroll Lewis, Lewis Carroll backwards

Given the many references and even a deliberate use of names, it makes me wonder if there is a specific reason that they decided to spell Alyce with a Y instead of Alice with an I like in the book.

Comment: FYI: The song "Go Ask Alice" is, I presume, *"White Rabbit"* by Jefferson Airplane (or a cover thereof.)  I don't have any sources for the spelling of the name, but I presume it was "just to be cool."  Certainly, the name "Alice" with an "i" is commonplace enough that it wouldn't have triggered any legal concerns against the parody the movie is making.

Comment: [Alyce? Alyce!? Who the f*$% is Alyce!?!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUy83PKjkOI)

Answer (score 3):

The film was originally announced as just *'Alyce'* to various horror-related websites.

[image] [image]

If it had been titled "*Alice*" (with a i), it would have been the [fifth film produced that year with the same title](https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title=%22Alice%22&title_type=feature,short&release_date=2011-01-01,2011-12-30) and the fourteenth horror film with 'Alice' in the title since 2005, making it much harder to find on sites like IMDB and to promote to festivals.

Choosing a title like '*Alyce*' (and then 'Alyce Kills') allows you to convey that this is a violent *Alice in Wonderland pastiche*, but makes it significantly easier to shop around.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Comment: @sanpaco - I'm annoyed at not being able to get hold of the Director. He did a lot of publicity and engagement in the past, but seems to have dropped off the face of the earth in the last three years.